# How to dump obj to xml in F#

Tags: f#

I try to tanslate a C# code to F#.
But faild.
Here is the C# code from a bolgpost called [LINQ Reduces Line Counts and Makes Code “Pop”](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericwhite/linq-reduces-line-counts-and-makes-code-pop)

It's about FP.

I translate it to

```
#r "System.Core.dll"
#r "System.Xml.Linq.dll"

open System
open System.Reflection
open System.Collections
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Xml.Linq

let (|V|S|A|O|) o =
    if o.GetType().IsValueType then V
    elif o.GetType()=typeof<string> then S
    elif o.GetType().IsArray then A
    else O

let rec obj2xml r o =
    match o with
    | V | S -> new XElement(r, o)
    | A -> o |> Array.map (fun z -> obj2xml r z)
    | O -> new XElement(r, o.GetType().GetProperties() |> Array.map (fun z -> obj2xml (z.Name) (z.GetValue(o, null))))
```

**| V | S -> new XElement(r, o)** return a **XElement**

**| A -> o |> Array.map (fun z -> obj2xml r z)** return a **Array**

I couldn't figure it out!

I haven't got it complied yet!

Help me please!

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not going to get you very far on SO.

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't work" mean? Do you mean that it's functionality isn't correct or that it doesn't compile/build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it won't compile is that all branches of `match` have to return the same type of object. Your current code returns either an `XElement` or an `Array`. Since the name of the function is `obj2xml`, I guess that the correct type is `XElement`.

That means you need to wrap the array in an `XElement` somehow. I'm going to guess that `r` is short for 'root' and that since all the other XElements returned have `r` as their first argument, you should pass that.

```
| A -> o |> Array.map (fun z -> obj2xml r z)
// change to:
| A -> new XElement(r, o |> Array.map (fun z -> obj2xml r z))
```

By the way, I don't know if you're using Visual Studio to write this code. If you are, then you probably want to specify your references via the project system rather than `#r` compiler directives.